# Share files and folders over two gateway 192.168.2.1 and 10.10.10.1 on the network 10.10.10.1

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, file-sharing, gateway

I have a DSL Broadband line with Static IP 10.10.10.155 and a Router connected to my PC. When I have to use internet with this router, we need to configure Internet Setup as Static IP.

In this case sharing files and folders on windows 7 is not accessible because my router gateway 192.168.2.1 is different from DSL line gateway 10.10.10.1.

Router Configuration: Internet Type: Static IP. IP Address: 10.10.10.155. Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0. Gateway: 10.10.10.1. DNS Server: 10.10.10.1 Alternate DNS Server: 8.8.8.8

But we disconnect router and connect my pc directly to DSL line by setting local area connection configuration, It is accessible shared files.

I am trying to share on same network of this IP Pool from ISP. My ISP gives an IP to each user from 10.10.10.2 ip pool. But my router ip is 192.168.2.1 thus it can't share to someone users from 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.10.255. But I can use other share files like from \10.10.10.62.

On the other hand when I connect Internet line to the pc directly, it shares files, folders and printer by changing in IPv4 Setting in Local Area Network (LAN). My settings: ip:10.10.10.155, subnet mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 10.10.10.1, DNS Server: 8.8.8.8.

This is the setting I have to put in router internet setting as static ip. Where my pc have a separate gateway of 192.168.2.1. But ISP gateway 10.10.10.1 is different. I think I've explain everything. Please guide me. SkypeID: Arifspj

Comment: Your setup is a bit difficult to understand and with many uncertainties. Could you maybe provide a drawing/sketch of your setup with the ip addresses? It seems especially weird that you can be on the same subnet as the address pool that your ISP gives you.

Comment: "My ISP gives an IP to each user from 10.10.10.2 ip pool." -- No.  It seems to be giving from the 10.10.10.0/24 pool.  10.10.10.2 is an address, not pool.  Regardless, there are multiple possible solutions.  One is a VPN, which is fairly safe, but may be overkill/more work than necessary.  You could also just open up the Server Message Block ports.  You might even want to use bridging instead of NAT.  Realize that your "ISP" is not giving you even a single public IP address (even temporarily).  They are giving a private IP, which is more restricted, and uncommon for commercial Internet access.

Comment: TOOGAM, thanks you understood my issue. But I want to share folders on windows 7 on gateway 10.10.10.1+ from a router ip 192.168.2.1 isp ip (10.10.10.155)

Answer (score 0):

To interpret your question as best I can, you have two setups:

- PC connected to ADSL Modem and using 10.x addressing
- PC connected to your own router, 192.x addressing

You seem to want the LAN access between devices while also connected to the internet, but currently you have to pick one or the other, not both.

What you need to do, if I've understood your description, is configure this:

```
[DSL Modem] - [Your Router] - All devices
```

The important bit here is to set your router to do WAN DHCP so that it can take a 10.x address from your ISP, do NAT itself and hand out 192.x addresses to all your computers who can then "see/share with" each other.